# DNS issue on firewall server

Tags: centos

We have a endian firewall setup on a Centos box for our company branch office. Now the problem is the following some sites eg. microsoft.com do not work when trying top open them up in browser, getting DNS error.

So what I did I switched off the firewall and still it did not work. Then I ssh'd into the firewall PC and tried to PING microsoft.com and I got

```
ping microsoft.com
ping: unknown host microsoft.com
```

So I tried to PING using the IP

I got the following

ping 65.55.21.250;
PING 65.55.21.250 (65.55.21.250) 56(84) bytes of data. and then it does nothing, I rebooted the PC and still nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few other things to consider:

- Checking the output of "traceroute microsoft.com", both from the firewall and one of your client PCs might tell you where the traffic's going (or rather, where the traffic's stopping).
- Also, what's your DNS setup like?  Do you run it internally, or use your ISP/OpenDNS/whoever for resolution?
- What happens if you query your nameserver directly with nslookup or dig?  If you've got an internal nameserver, try checking both that and whatever server it refers queries out to.  It's possible that your firewall's somehow blocking outbound DNS.

Comment: traceroute microsoft.com just hangs

Comment: although traceroute google.com works

Comment: OK, try "traceroute -n microsoft.com" instead; that'll stop it trying to do a DNS lookup on everything it encounters on the way.  Sorry, should have said.

Comment: I appreciate your help.

I now get 

traceroute -n microsoft.com
traceroute: unknown host microsoft.com

Comment: This is how the resolv.conf file looks cat /etc/resolv.conf nameserver 127.0.0.1

Comment: OK, this definitely looks like a DNS issue.  Comment out that "nameserver" line, and add another one with the IP address of either your DNS server or your ISP's one (or both), then try again.

Comment: I changed the nameserver 127.0.0.1 to nameserver Breakout IP address and this fixed the Issue. Thank you, now I solved my issue and learned something new

Answer (score 2):

What is your DNS servers?
(cat /etc/resolv.conf)

Try to add\change them to other

Comment: This is how the resolv.conf file looks

cat /etc/resolv.conf
nameserver 127.0.0.1